# Is my motherboard broken?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I restarted my computer yesterday morning . It started to boot back up, but hung on the motherboards' boot screen. I could not select any options with my keyboard, which was working at the time. The mobo had an LED saying 92 - which in the ASRock book states PCI-E device initializing. I have attempted to reboot both with my graphics card (Radeon HD 6790) and without it. I have had no luck getting past this splash screen. AFAIK there are no other PCI-E devices attached. I have removed and replaced the CMOS battery as well as pushed the Reset CMOS button. I have removed all other devices, sans RAM and video cable directly to the mobo, with no effect. My processor is the AMD A8-3800.  My gut says the board is dead. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: When you removed the CMOS battery, how long did you leave it out? Try leaving it out for, say, half an hour... although the "Reset CMOS" should do the same thing, I'm often not sure whether it truly clears the CMOS... taking the battery out for a decent amount of time should force all the devices and capacitors etc. to fully drain...

Comment: I left it out for about 10 seconds or so - but I suppose it can't hurt to try for longer.

Comment: If you have multiple RAM strips, try with only 1 of them. And try different RAM slots. If you have a broken RAM-strip or slot in some cases it may show as any other error in stead of a RAM error. Swap them all around to see if that is the case. But it does sound as if the motherboard is dead... You seem to have ruled out anything else already.

Comment: What code do you get with your graphics card removed also do you have any other cards you can remove

Comment: I have only 1 graphics card, and I still get 92 when its removed.

Comment: remove the gfx card again and blow (gently!  no spittle!) into the pci/e slots.    There could be some hair or dust or other in there that is shorting things out.  It's a long shot, but give it a try anyway